# Resttemplate post method with autorization is not working with exchange method

Tags: java, rest, web-services, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to consume a rest service with authorization using the below code. I'm getting Status Code 200 with 404 result. The same params execute correctly via Postman. Can you please advise what to fix?

```
@Test
public void addEnterpriseTest() {
    HttpHeaders headers1 = new HttpHeaders();           
    headers1.put("Authorization", Arrays.asList("Bearer 123"));
    headers1.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

    String uri = PROVISIONING_END_POINT + "enterprises";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("Id=8888&Name=MyEnperprise", headers);     
    ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);

    System.out.println(result.getStatusCode()); //getting 200   
    System.out.println(result); //getting 404       
}
```

Comment: what type of authentication you are using ? is it OAuth ?

Comment: It is Transport Layer Security and token